# HashSet<T>.RemoveWhere() and GetHashCode()

Tags: c#

Aloha,

Here's a simple class that overrides GetHashCode:

```
class OverridesGetHashCode
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Text != null ? Text.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
    // overriding Equals() doesn't change anything, so I'll leave it out for brevity
}
```

When I create an instance of that class, add it to a HashSet and then change its Text property, like this:

```
var hashset = new HashSet<OverridesGetHashCode>();
var oghc = new OverridesGetHashCode { Text = "1" };
hashset.Add(oghc);
oghc.Text = "2";
```

then this doesn't work:

```
var removedCount = hashset.RemoveWhere(c => ReferenceEquals(c, oghc));
// fails, nothing is removed
Assert.IsTrue(removedCount == 1);
```

and neither does this:

```
// this line works, i.e. it does find a single item matching the predicate
var existing = hashset.Single(c => ReferenceEquals(c, oghc));
// but this fails; nothing is removed again
var removed = hashset.Remove(existing);
Assert.IsTrue(removed);
```

I guess the hash it internally uses is generated when item is inserted and, if that's true, it's
understandable that hashset.Contains(oghc) doesn't work. 
I also guess it looks up item by its hash code and if it finds a match, only then it checks the predicate, and that might be why the first test fails (again, I'm just guessing here). 
But why does the last test fail, I just got that object out of the hashset? Am I missing something, is this a wrong way to remove something from a HashSet?

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

UPDATE: To avoid confusion, here's the Equals():

```
protected bool Equals(OverridesGetHashCode other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Text, other.Text);
    }

public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((OverridesGetHashCode) obj);
    }
```

Comment: You should probably take a look at Eric Lippert's [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) particularly the rule *the integer returned by GetHashCode must never change while the object is contained in a data structure that depends on the hash code remaining stable*.

Comment: I first thought this was a good question, now I feel like I asked something really stupid :) It all makes sense after a while, it just felt counter-intuitive at first. 'I never used HashSet before' is the best excuse I can come up with :D Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good answers here and just wanted to add this. If you look at the decompiled `HashSet<T>` code, you'll see that `Add(value)` does the following:

1. Calls [`IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132155.aspx) to get the hash code for value. For the default comparer this boils down to `GetHashCode()`.
2. Uses that hash code to calculate which "bucket" and "slot" the (reference to) value should be stored in.
3. Stores the reference.

When you call `Remove(value)` it does steps 1. and 2. again, to find where the reference is at. Then it calls [`IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132154.aspx) to make sure that it indeed has found the right value. However, since you've changed what `GetHashCode()` returns, it calculates a different bucket/slot location, which is invalid. Thus, it cannot find the object.

So, note that `Equals()` doesn't really come into play here, because it will never even get to the right bucket/slot location if the hash code changes.

Answer (score 4):

By changing the hash code of your object while that object is being used in a `HashSet` is a violation of the `HashSet`'s contract.

Being unable to remove the object is not the problem here. **You are not allowed to change the hash code in the first place.**

Let me quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx):

> The GetHashCode method for an object must **consistently** return the same
>   hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state that
>   determines the return value of the object's Equals method. Note that
>   this is true only for the current execution of an application, and
>   that a different hash code can be returned if the application is run
>   again.

They tell the story a little differently but the essence is the same. They say, the hash code can *never* change. In practice, you can change it as long as you make sure no one uses the old hash code anymore. Not that this is good practice, but it works.

Comment: it could be argued that there was a *modification to the object state that determines the return value of the object's Equals method*

Comment: The edited quote is an entirely different issue here.  An object with the same data should return the same hash code, but since the object now has different data is has a right to return a different hash code (it *shouldn't* return the same one after mutating it).

Comment: @Usr "as long as there is no modification to the object state that determines the return value of the object's Equals'.  Presumably, if the objects are being compared for equality based on the value of Text, it makes sense for GetHashCode() to return a value based on the value of Text, even if Text is subject to change.

Comment: That suggests that you *can* change the `GetHashCode` value, but only if the `Equals` method reflects this change.  Since the OP didn't show their code for `Equals`, it could be this that they're violating.

Comment: `Equals` is largely irrelevant here.

Answer (score 4):

It's important that any items added to a hash based table (`HashSet`, `Dictionary`, etc.) not be modified once they are inserted into the structure (at least not until they are removed).

To find an object in the data structure it computes it hash code, and then finds a location based on that hash code.  If you mutate that object then the hash code it returns no longer reflects it's current location in that data structure (unless you're very, very lucky and it just happens to be a hash collision).

On the [MSDN page for Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is says:

> As long as an object is used as a key in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, it must not change in any way that affects its hash value.

This same assertion applies to `HashSet` as well, as they both are implemented using hash tables.

Comment: Yep.  In the above example, if you do hashset.RemoveWhere(x=>true), it still won't remove anything.  The predicate is true, but the hashset can't find the object.